# Prevent child process from system calls

Tags: c++, unix, process

I want to create a child process that call another program (with C++ in Unix). But I want to restrict the child process not to call system(), fopen(), etc. (if it did, it would be terminated).

How to do that?

Comment: I want to create a simple and personal grader for programming contest problem, so if the solution calls system(), it will report "Illegal system call" or something like that.

Comment: If I am not much mistaken, ejugde is open-source. Maybe you could take a look at how it's done there?

Answer (score 2):

[this](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ptrace) might help you. It seems there is a way of handling different things a child process does via ptrace. HTH

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your child process uses the C library to do the syscalls, it's a dynamic executable, and your system uses ELF, you could set LD_PRELOAD to a library that intercepts the functions you are interested in.

Failing that, you could do a Valgrind tool.

Answer (score 0):

Tricky.  If this is Linux or BSD, you might experiment with `setrlimit(RLIMIT_NPROC, &lim)`.  This won't terminate the child if it tries to create a process, but it will cause the system call to `fork` to fail.  No clue if there's any more portable answer.

Comment: @Peter - Hm, yes, that would be a security hole too.  Armen's answer is probably better (assuming it works on the OS to be used).